# Как задать для JButton код которое будет выполнять действия

Tags: java, swing

У меня такая загвоздка возникла:
Есть файл Xml в котором содержаться данные которые нужно скопировать и вставить в конкретные места в файле word.docx.

Все работает, но захотел сделать интерфейс и никак не могу понять как сделать все грамотно и чтобы работало.

Внешний вид сделал простой, файлы выбирать могу. Но не знаю куда вставить основную часть кода чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялась эта функция

Вид интерфейса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно что есть 2-а JTextField`a і JFileChooser.

Файлы выбирать могу все прочее.

Так как тепер файлы я буду выбирать вручную, а не сразу писать расположение где они находятся:

```
public class AutoForm {

public static String input_DOCX = "C:\\\\Users\\\\UserPC\\\\Desktop\\\\Myartifact\\\\bilous.docx";

public static String input_XML = "C:\\Users\\UserPC\\Desktop\\Myartifact\\bilous.xml";

public static String output_DOCX = "C:\\Users\\\\UserPC\\Desktop\\Myartifact\\output.docx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);
}
```

}

Тепер вместо input_DOCX, input_XML, output_DOCX я выбираю файлы вручную, а не прописываю.

В чем мой вопрос хочу чтобы этот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);
}
```

начинал работать как только я виберу файлы и нажму на кнопку "Process"

Код интерфейса интерфейса:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

      import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JTextField;


     import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
      import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
       import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;

     public class Gui {

    private JFrame frame;
     private JTextField input1;
     private JTextField input2;
     private JButton btnBrowserXml;
   private JButton btnRun;



  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       try {
           Gui window = new Gui();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the application.
   */
  public Gui() {
    initialize();
  }

  /**
   * Initialize the contents of the frame.
   */
  private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    input1 = new JTextField();
    input1.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(input1);
    input1.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse Docx");
    btnBrowse.setBounds(10, 41, 104, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);


    input2 = new JTextField();
    input2.setBounds(11, 73, 413, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(input2);
    input2.setColumns(10);

    btnBrowserXml = new JButton("Browse Xml");
    btnBrowserXml.setBounds(10, 104, 104, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowserXml);




    btnRun = new JButton("Process");
    btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




          }});


                /*
                 * try { WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new
                 * File(input1.getText())); } catch (Docx4JException e1) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e1.printStackTrace(); } try { FileInputStream
                 * xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input2.getText())); } catch
                 * (FileNotFoundException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e1.printStackTrace(); }
                 * 
                 * Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML |
                 * Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
                 * Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(Result.setToolTipText("output.docx")),
                 * Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
                 */




    btnRun.setBounds(168, 203, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRun);

    JLabel lblResult = new JLabel("Result");
    lblResult.setBounds(10, 137, 166, 35);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblResult);





    // File Docx   
    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        // For File
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        int rVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          input1.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
        }
      }
    });

    // File XML
    btnBrowserXml.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

          // For File
          fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

          fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

          int rVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
          if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              input2.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
          }
        }
      });} }
```

Кто знающий, скажите как правильно сделать по уму. Или пример скиньте какой-то. Заранее благодарю)

Comment: У Вас там все уже есть - `btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {...your code...}});`

Comment: Когда я ставлю этот кусок кода

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);
}
Выбиваеть ошибка когда ставлю без public static тоже.